# CSS dropdown button not expanding on second button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm unclear why but the dropdown function only seems to work on the first button and not the second. When clicking the second button it opens the drop-down for the first button. Am I selecting my elements wrong?

Example here: https://jsfiddle.net/rzLfs8um/

```
  function calDropdown() {
    document.getElementById("calDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
  }

  // Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
  window.onclick = function (event) {
    if (!event.target.matches(".cal-dropbtn")) {
      var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("cal-dropdown-content");
      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
        var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
        if (openDropdown.classList.contains("show")) {
          openDropdown.classList.remove("show");
        }
      }
    }
  };
```

Comment: Here is fixed version, you shouldn't give same id to more than one elements. https://jsfiddle.net/4h6L7rqy/

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you are using same ID `calDropdown` for both dropdowns.

I have updated the id for second dropdown as `calDropdown2` and passed the id from the onclick function

```js
  function calDropdown(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).classList.toggle("show");
  }

  // Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
  window.onclick = function (event) {
    if (!event.target.matches(".cal-dropbtn")) {
      var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("cal-dropdown-content");
      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
        var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
        if (openDropdown.classList.contains("show")) {
          openDropdown.classList.remove("show");
        }
      }
    }
  };
```

```css
.cal-dropbtn {
        margin: 0;
    font-family: "Verdana";
    font-size: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    box-shadow: 0 0 40px rgba(0,0,0,.13) inset;
    border-radius: 4px;
    zoom: 1;
    background: #fbfbfb;
    color: #5f6062;
    padding: 7px 15px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border: none;
}

.cal-dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.cal-dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.cal-dropdown-content a {
    color: #5f6062;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.cal-dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.show {display:block;}

.far.fa-calendar-alt {
    margin-right: .25em;
}
```

```html
<div class="cal-dropdown">
    <button onclick="calDropdown('calDropdown')" class="cal-dropbtn">
      <i class="far fa-calendar-alt">&nbsp;</i>Add to Calendar</button>
      <div id="calDropdown" class="cal-dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Google Calendar</a>
      <a href="#">Outlook</a>
      <a href="#">Yahoo! Calendar</a>
      <a href="#">Apple iCal</a>
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="cal-dropdown">
    <button onclick="calDropdown('calDropdown2')" class="cal-dropbtn">
      <i class="far fa-calendar-alt">&nbsp;</i>Add to Calendar</button>
      <div id="calDropdown2" class="cal-dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Google Calendar</a>
      <a href="#">Outlook</a>
      <a href="#">Yahoo! Calendar</a>
      <a href="#">Apple iCal</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Never declare js events inside html tags. Like this:

```
onclick="calDropdown()"
```

This can lead to **bad consequences**.

And don't use one `id` for many tags. This is a unique attribute.

Here is a short js code using method `forEach()` and `nextElementSibling`.

```js
let btn = document.querySelectorAll(".cal-dropbtn");  
   
btn.forEach(function(btn_current) {
  btn_current.addEventListener("click", function () {
    this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('show');
  });
});
```

```css
.cal-dropbtn {
        margin: 0;
    font-family: "Verdana";
    font-size: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    box-shadow: 0 0 40px rgba(0,0,0,.13) inset;
    border-radius: 4px;
    zoom: 1;
    background: #fbfbfb;
    color: #5f6062;
    padding: 7px 15px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border: none;
}

.cal-dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.cal-dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.cal-dropdown-content a {
    color: #5f6062;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.cal-dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.show {display:block;}

.far.fa-calendar-alt {
    margin-right: .25em;
}
```

```html
<div class="cal-dropdown">
    <button class="cal-dropbtn">
      <i class="far fa-calendar-alt">&nbsp;</i>Add to Calendar</button>
      <div class="cal-dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Google Calendar</a>
        <a href="#">Outlook</a>
        <a href="#">Yahoo! Calendar</a>
        <a href="#">Apple iCal</a>
      </div>
</div>

<div class="cal-dropdown">
    <button class="cal-dropbtn">
      <i class="far fa-calendar-alt">&nbsp;</i>Add to Calendar</button>
      <div class="cal-dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Google Calendar</a>
        <a href="#">Outlook</a>
        <a href="#">Yahoo! Calendar</a>
        <a href="#">Apple iCal</a>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Even better would be delegation from nearest static container

Comment: Clicking outside the dropdowns doesn't close the dropdowns.....check it out

Comment: @RedemptionOkoro, I did not pay attention to this point. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

ID is, as the name suggest, a unique identifier. It means you can only have one element with an ID on the page. If you somehow screw up and you render two elements with the same ID on the page you can only select the first one with `document.getElementById()` since the second one is invalid.

If you have multiple elements on the page you want to target then use classes.

Comment: Thank you, I made some adjustments and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution

```
    <div class="cal-dropdown">
    <button onclick="calDropdown(this)" class="cal-dropbtn"><i class="far fa-calendar-alt">&nbsp;</i>Add to Calendar</button>
      <div id="calDropdown" class="cal-dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Google Calendar</a>
      <a href="#">Outlook</a>
      <a href="#">Yahoo! Calendar</a>
      <a href="#">Apple iCal</a>
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="cal-dropdown">
    <button onclick="calDropdown(this)" class="cal-dropbtn"><i class="far fa-calendar-alt">&nbsp;</i>Add to Calendar</button>
      <div id="calDropdown" class="cal-dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Google Calendar</a>
      <a href="#">Outlook</a>
      <a href="#">Yahoo! Calendar</a>
      <a href="#">Apple iCal</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
.cal-dropbtn {
        margin: 0;
    font-family: "Verdana";
    font-size: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    box-shadow: 0 0 40px rgba(0,0,0,.13) inset;
    border-radius: 4px;
    zoom: 1;
    background: #fbfbfb;
    color: #5f6062;
    padding: 7px 15px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border: none;
}

.cal-dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.cal-dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.cal-dropdown-content a {
    color: #5f6062;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.cal-dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.show {display:block;}

.far.fa-calendar-alt {
    margin-right: .25em;
}
```

```
function calDropdown(el) {
    console.log('---asdasd', el.parentNode)
    el.parentNode.querySelector('.cal-dropdown-content').classList.toggle("show");
  }
```